# Screen density and emulator

Tags: android, screen

I'm trying to test my application on different screen sizes and densities. To do this, I created several AVDs.

One of them is defined with a WVGA800 screen. This AVD should hence have a large screen with a density of 240. This clearly is a high density display.

My problem is that when I run my application in this AVD, if I call the `c.getdensity()` function in the `onDraw` method of my custom view class, it returns 160, which corresponds to a medium density screen. This is consistent with the fact that the application takes the drawable resources in my "mdpi" folder and not in my "hdpi" folder.

What is wrong and how can I create a large screen high density AVD?

Thanks in advance for the time your will spend trying to help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the source of the problem. I had to explicitly declare in the "AndroidManifest" file that my application supports any screen density by using, outside the application block, the `<supports-screens>` tag.

Seems Eclipse automatically adds this feature to the generated code.

Answer (score 1):

When creating New AVD from Android AVD Manager change the value of ***Abstracted LCD density*** from Hardware section.

You can get help from here http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html#createavd

Comment: OK, I already suspected the "Abstract LCD Density" parameter. The problem is that my AVD, as displayed in the SDK manager's editor, has this parameter set to 240 already!!

Comment: Well, seems it's a Netbeans's bug. A simple application only showing an image always displays the mdpi image when compiled with Netbeans and shows the correct image when compiled with Eclipse.